# maven test plugin to see how good my tests are

Tags: maven, testing, plugins

i remember from long time ago that there was a plugin that would run my tests, then by bytecode manipulation switched branches or added null values and then expected my tests to fail somewhere, but i dont remember anymore how it is called, do you dear reader know, for instance given my method:

```
 calc(int first, int second, string operator){
if(operator.equals("add)){ return first + second}
```

and an useless testcase

```
test:
calc(1,2,"add")
```

since there is no assert here my source could always return 1, this test plugin would capture these kind of tests and mark them as bad

Comment: There two things you could take into account. The first one is [jacoco-maven-plugin](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) which measures your code coverage and the second one is using mutation tetsing where [pitest-maven](https://pitest.org/quickstart/) is the right way to go

Comment: yes thanks pitest was the plugin i was remembering